# can't compile custom component dynamically in nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, p3x-angular-compile

I'm using a Angular Dynamic Compile component called `P3X Angular Compile`, that turns a string into a compiled component in my nativescript project.
link : https://npm.taobao.org/package/p3x-angular-compile .
I install that via `npm` in my {N} project but it did not work, so I use a part of `P3X`'s source code in my project and create a `dynamic-component-builder` like this :

**dynamic-component.ts:**

```
export class DynamicComponentBuilder implements OnChanges {

@Input('template') html: string;
@Input('module') module: NgModule;
@Input('parent') context: any;
@Input('error-handler') errorHandler: Function = undefined;
@Input('imports') imports: Array<Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders | any[]>;

dynamicComponent: any;
dynamicModule: NgModuleFactory<any> | any;

constructor(private compiler: Compiler) { }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.update();
}

update() {
    try {
        if (this.html === undefined || this.html === null || this.html.trim() === '') {
            this.dynamicComponent = undefined;
            this.dynamicModule = undefined;
            return;
        }
        this.dynamicComponent = this.createNewComponent(this.html, this.context);
        this.dynamicModule = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(this.createComponentModule(this.dynamicComponent));

    } catch (e) {
        if (this.errorHandler === undefined)
            throw e;
        else
            this.errorHandler(e);
    }
}

createComponentModule(componentType: any) {
    let module: NgModule = {};
    if (this.module !== undefined)
        module = cloneDeep(this.module);

    module.imports = module.imports || [];
    module.imports.push(CommonModule);
    if (this.imports !== undefined)
        module.imports = module.imports.concat(this.imports)

    if (module.declarations === undefined)
        module.declarations = [componentType];
    else
        module.declarations.push(componentType);

    module.entryComponents = [componentType];

    @NgModule(module)
    class RuntimeComponentModule { }
    return RuntimeComponentModule;
}


createNewComponent(html: string, context: any) {
    @Component({
        selector: nextId(),
        template: html
    })
    class DynamicComponent {
        context: any = context;
    }
    return DynamicComponent;
}
}
```

**dynamic-component.html:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="html !== undefined && html !== null && html.trim() !=='' ">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dynamicComponent; ngModuleFactory: 
 dynamicModule;"> </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

and I use this component like this:

**customPage.html:**

```
<StackLayout dynamic [template]="myListCmp" [module]="myListMd" [parent]="this"></StackLayout>
<StackLayout dynamic [template]="textField" [parent]="this"></StackLayout>
```

**customPage.ts:**

```
textField= "<TextField hint='Enter date'></TextField>";
myListCmp= "<my-list></my-list>";
myListMd= { entryComponents: [ MyListComponent ] }
```

the component work with `textField` correctly but with my custom `my-list` component not working and get the following errors: 
`ERROR Error: Can't compile synchronously as MyListComponent is still being loaded!`

`ERROR Error: No component factory found for DynamicComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

I need to mention that `my-list` component is declared in a custom Module.

Please Help! thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `my-list` component is not visible to the p3x compiler plugin.

Comment: Should it be `entryComponents` instead of `entityComponents` in `myListMd= { entityComponents: [ MyListComponent ] }`? In your customPage.ts file

Comment: @John thank you. That typing error occurred in my question. But I wrote in the correct code and still get error

Comment: Did you add your custom Module to AppModule as well? Are you exporting MyListComponent?

Comment: yes. I import my custom Module to AppModule. also exported MyListComponent.